# Add file to RAR without keeping folder structure

Tags: linux, centos, rar

I'm running this command:

```
rar u /var/www/html/Backups44.rar /var/www/html/linkreplacer/MD5Change
```

I want to add the file "MD5Change" to the rar "Backups44" but whenever i run this it adds all the folders into it aswell, Link /var/www/html/linkreplacer/ then the file is in there.

How can i add just the file without all the folders ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `-ep` argument to [Exclude Paths](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/rar.1.html) while adding files.

Try something like:

`rar u -ep /var/www/html/Backups44.rar /var/www/html/linkreplacer/MD5Change`